# Is this how an MVC controller supposed to be?

Tags: php, mvc

This is the controller I created for my MVC framework, and I think I finally got it right.

Anything I can do to make the code more efficient?

Is this how a MVC controller is supposed to look like?

```
abstract class Controller
{
    protected $requestHandler;

    public function __construct(RequestHandler $rh, $action)
    {
        $this->requestHandler = $rh;

        $this->$action();
    }

    protected abstract function index();
}

class SignUpController extends Controller
{
    protected function index()
    {
        $headerData = array(
            'title' => 'Sign up',
            'stylesheets' => ['/stylesheets/signup.css'],
            'scripts' => array(
                '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js',
                '/javascripts/misc.js'
            )
        );

        View::render('Header', $headerData);

        if ($this->requestHandler->getMethod() === 'POST') {
            $v = new Validator();

            $v->addRule(1, ['required', 'max' => 35]);
            $v->addRule(2, ['required', 'between' => [5, 255], 'email']);
            $v->addRule(3, ['required', 'min' => 6]);
            $v->addRule(4, ['required']);

            $firstname    = $v->validate(1, (isset($_POST['firstname']))    ? trim($_POST['firstname'])    : false);
            $lastname     = $v->validate(1, (isset($_POST['lastname']))     ? trim($_POST['lastname'])     : false);
            $email        = $v->validate(2, (isset($_POST['email']))        ? trim($_POST['email'])        : false);
            $emailConfirm = $v->validate(2, (isset($_POST['emailConfirm'])) ? trim($_POST['emailConfirm']) : false);
            $password     = $v->validate(3, (isset($_POST['password']))     ?      $_POST['password']      : false);
            $terms        = $v->validate(4,  isset($_POST['terms']));

            if ($emailConfirm === true && trim($_POST['email']) !== trim($_POST['emailConfirm'])) {
                $emailConfirm = $v->setError('match');
            }

            if (!$v->errors()) {
                //user sign up logic here

                View::render('SignUpSuccess', ['email' => trim($_POST['email'])]);
            } else {
                $signUpData = array(
                    'firstname'    => $firstname,
                    'fnVal'        => (isset($_POST['firstname'])) ? $_POST['firstname'] : false,
                    'lastname'     => $lastname,
                    'lnVal'        => (isset($_POST['lastname'])) ? $_POST['lastname'] : false,
                    'email'        => $email,
                    'emVal'        => (isset($_POST['email'])) ? $_POST['email'] : false,
                    'emailConfirm' => $emailConfirm,
                    'emConfVal'    => (isset($_POST['emailConfirm'])) ? $_POST['emailConfirm'] : false,
                    'password'     => $password,
                    'pwVal'        => (isset($_POST['password'])) ? $_POST['password'] : false,
                    'terms'        => $terms,
                    'termsVal'     => isset($_POST['terms'])
                );

                View::render('SignUp', $signUpData);
            }
        } else {
            View::render('SignUp');
        }

        View::render('Footer');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[MVC has a strict definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller). However, frameworks don't actually follow MVC (yet they call themselves such). It's like a free-for-all on framework design, approaches can differ.

Enough of that theory, let's do code.

One issue here is the constructor. If the class is subclassed, but doesn't call the parent when the constructor is overridden, then nothing will run. I suggest you separate a router logic from the controller. The order should be like

Also, I think it's best you place all request data (parameters, headers) into an object, like a `$request` parameter handed into the function that's called in the controller by the router (pre-cleaned and pre-formatted). Also, throw in getters to normalize the data, so that you won't be doing 'isset` all the time. Something like:

```
$pass = $req->post('password'); // Gets the password param from a post request, else false
```

Don't render by parts, like header, content, footer in the controller. It's best you invest in having a templating system. The template has the fully formed HTML, and all your render does is fill in the blanks. [See mustache templates](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php), you might like it.

So the order is:

1. Receive request (in CodeIgniter, that's the `index.php`)
2. `index.php` loads core libraries and dependencies (like routers, url parsers, db driver, XSS prevention, stuff like that).
3. Parse the request and simplify where needed. What you could do is

   - Sanitize all inputs from XSS and SQL injections.
   - Normalize input by placing encapsulating them in an object. Throw in a getter, so that you only need to call something like `$request->post('password')` to get the password from a POST request.
4. Then the router determines the route from the request, includes that class, creates an instance, and executes the appropriate method. Something like `$classInstance->theAction($normalizedRequestData)`
5. Now we are in the controller. Controller then talks to the model, do something here and there, gets the data, and renders the view with the data from the DB.

   ```
   $this->render('VIEW_NAME',$dataFromDB);
   ```
6. Template parser kicks in, renders the data and generates the HTML which then gets send back to browser.

If you're a visual guy like I am, I'd prefer to look at a diagram rather than a wall of text. Luckily, [CodeIgniter drew their data flow](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/overview/appflow.html), which got me sold. It's pretty handy diagram, which can be used as basis for framework design.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thing that bugs me about this is that `Controller::__construct` is basically handling the whole request.  A constructor should be doing as little work as possible -- ideally *only* getting the object ready to use.

The problem is that otherwise, your request is never really handled.  That can be resolved by simply renaming the constructor.  (It's really a dispatcher, so a good name would mention that.)

Also, the action method in `SignUpController` is a bit too familiar with how the page is laid out.  Your view should generally be handling the rendering of the header and footer.

Comment: So the controller constructor should only get/set the dependency injected objects? Also, isn't the controller supposed to "control" what happens, which view is rendered where in the page layout? So aside from rendering the main content view in the controller, I should render the header and footer inside my view templates and not the controller?

Comment: @KidDiamond: The controller coordinates the flow of messages.  In web-style "MVC" (really more akin to front-controller), it might decide which view and/or model is appropriate.  Ideally, though, it does little to nothing else, and doesn't care (much less dictate) what the view does.  If you're separating your concerns properly, then the view and controller are near-totally independent -- you could rearrange everything on the page without the controller having to change at all.

Comment: In truth, i'm kinda thinking the constructor shouldn't exist here (or if it does, it should take no params and do no work).  If you pass it the request info and then say `$controller->handleRequest();` or the like, all you're really doing is turning methods into half-procedures...separating the passing of params from the procedure that actually uses them.  I'd rather see a `public function dispatchRequest($request, $action)`, personally...or possibly even do away with that, and have your action methods take `$rh` as a parameter, if you really need it, and leave request routing to a router.

Comment: I already am using my request handler with my router. And my router routes to the correct controller and action. The reason I'm using the request handler in my controller is that the request handler knows the request method (GET, POST, etc) so I can do things based on the condition. Why would I sent the $rh object as a parameter in the action? Every action is going to need it as a parameter, while in the constructor I can actually set it once and use that in every action.

Comment: @KidDiamond:  You can...and in many cases, it makes sense.  But it is only worthwhile if `$rh` may be unknown when the request is being handled (which can not possibly be the case here, since the request ends up responded to before you even finish *constructing* your controller).   If you do it unnecessarily, you're just splitting `$controller->$action($rh)` in two for the sake of doing so, which gains you nothing but obscurity.